# How to delete a user in asana from my workspace?

Tags: asana

I had added one of my client in workspace, now I want to delete him from my workspace, how do I go about it ?

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions. You will be better off contacting Asana support.

Answer (score 9):

1. Navigate to your workspace.
2. Click the cog (workspace settings) icon to the right of workspace bar.
3. Select "Invite and Manage Members".
4. Click the "Remove" button next to member you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have a premium account, the above solution will not work. Asana will just tell you to upgrade.  This article https://asana.com/guide/help/organizations/basics#gl-free-depro
explains how to do this for the free version.

[image: To remove a person's access, do it from the team cog menu]

Answer (score 0):

I've included a few screenshots (Sep, 2017) that show how you can do this with the Free version.

1. [Go to "Everyone" in the Navigation Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reKv9.png)
2. [Hover over the user and click "Remove" in the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pumj.png)
3. [Click "Remove Access" in the section that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygBY.png)

You'll be able to further "Deprovision" the member once you click "Remove Access". Doing so will remove them from any project they were previously added to.